# Javax.Xml Not present in JRE 1.1

Tags: xml-parsing, java

I have created a program in Java which edit/read a XML file. I have done it using Javax.xml package and org.w3c package. The program runs fine on JRE 1.6 but the same code when runs on JRE 1.1 throws exception of java.lang.noclassdeffounderror javax/xml/parsers/documentbuilder. I did my own investigation in this issue and got to know that Javax package is not provided in JRE 1.1. Is there a way I can run this program on JRE 1.1, by somehow able to include or reference this package using a jar or any other thing possible?

Thanks,
Amit Singh

Comment: You could use any xml parsing library.  You may need really old version that works with jre 1.1..

Comment: you need to bundle the required libraries with your app. However, I'm not sure which libraries would actually be JRE 1.1 compliant. JRE 1.1 is over 15 years old already.